# Use regular expression to find/replace substring in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, ios5

I would like to use regular expression to find every instances of a regular expression pattern I.e. `&*;` in my string and remove that from  so the return value is the original string without any of the matches. Also would like to use the same function to match multiple spaces between words and have a single space instead. Could not find such a function.

Sample input string

```
NSString *str = @"123 &1245; Ross Test  12";
```

Return value should be

```
123 Ross Test 12
```

If anything matching this pattern `"&*` or multiple  white spaces and replaces it with `@"";`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"123 &1245; Ross Test 12";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"&[^;]*;" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Comment: In ObjC you should use nil instead of NULL. But NULL works too, since it is C.

Answer (score 14):

String replacing code using regex in String extension

**Objective-C**

```
@implementation NSString(RegularExpression)

- (NSString *)replacingWithPattern:(NSString *)pattern withTemplate:(NSString *)withTemplate error:(NSError **)error {
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:error];
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                                      withTemplate:withTemplate];
}

@end
```

resolve

```
NSString *string = @"123 &1245; Ross Test  12";
// remove all matches string
NSString *result = [string replacingWithPattern:@"&[\\d]+?;" withTemplate:@"" error:nil];
// result = "123  Ross Test  12"
```

or more

```
NSString *string = @"123 +   456";
// swap number
NSString *result = [string replacingWithPattern:@"([\\d]+)[ \\+]+([\\d]+)" withTemplate:@"$2 + $1" error:nil];
// result = 456 + 123
```

**Swift2**

```
extension String {
    func replacing(pattern: String, withTemplate: String) throws -> String {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(self, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<self.utf16.count), withTemplate: withTemplate)
    }
}
```

**Swift3**

```
extension String {
    func replacing(pattern: String, withTemplate: String) throws -> String {
        let regex = try RegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<self.utf16.count), withTemplate: withTemplate)
    }
}
```

use

```
var string = "1!I 2\"want 3#to 4$remove 5%all 6&digit and a char right after 7'from 8(string"
do {
    let result = try string.replacing("[\\d]+.", withTemplate: "")
} catch {
    // error
}
// result = "I want to remove all digit and a char right after from string"
```

Comment: Would be better rename function name to `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingWithPattern:(NSString *)pattern withTemplate:(NSString *)withTemplate error:(NSError **)error`

Comment: would be better to remove all those with