# Use regex to find and extract substrings from a string

Tags: ios, regex

Suppose I have the following string:

> bla bla bla bla i don't know what to write START **name 1** END more
> bla bla bla bla i don't know what to write START **name 2** END  more
> bla bla bla bla i don't know what to write START **name 3** END

And I want to extract the following array:

> name 1
>
> name 2
>
> name 3

What is the best way to do it with the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
NSArray *names = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"START"];

NSArray *namesArray = [NSArray array];

for (int i = 1; i < [names count]; i++) {
    NSString *thisLine = [names objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name = [thisLine substringToIndex:[thisLine rangeOfString:@"END"].location];

    [namesArray addObject:name];
    NSLog(@"Your name: %@", name);
}
```

Just noticed you wanted this with Regex... This is not that of course, but maybe it helps!

Comment: indeed, this is a solution! +1 that it helps me, but i'm pretty curious how I could do it with Regex

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=START ).*?(?= END)"
```

See also [Use regular expression to find/replace substring in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/user-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with regex:

```
(?<=START\s)(.+?)(?=\sEND)
```