# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString loop?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *qwer2 = [qwer1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"count '0','" withString:@""];

NSString *qwer4 = [qwer2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"count '1','" withString:@""];

NSString *qwer = [qwer4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"count '2','" withString:@""];
```

How can I replacing string with any numbers ?

> count '0' , count '1' , count '2'
>
> count 'any numbers'

I already tried the loop:

```
for (int i =0; i<100; i++)
```

NSString *qwer = [qwer4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"count 'i','" withString:@""];

Comment: This question is a little unclear.  Are you trying to generate a list of strings that say Count 1 Count 2 Count 2 etc?  (Also you should tag this post with Objective-C)

Comment: no i want replace string "count '0','" -> ""

Comment: and there's many count '0' count '1' .... count 'x'

Comment: this number is random numbers..

Comment: I would look into regular expressions and do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/user-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring)

Comment: ill try Matthias Bauch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
NSString *qwer1 = @"My string count '0', count '1', count '2', count '3', count '4',";
for (int i =0; i<5; i++) {
    NSString *count = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count '%i',", i];
    qwer1 = [qwer1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:count withString:@""];
}
NSLog(@"%@", [qwer1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]);
```

Comment: Yes this is more like it, only problem is you are leaving a lot of white spaces which needs cleaning as well. Converted my down vote to up vote though.

Comment: We can use `[NSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *replaced = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"count '\\d+','"
                           withString:@""
                              options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

should do the trick. "\d+" is  a regular expression pattern that matches one or more digits.

Comment: Little typo though, it should be `@"count '\\d',"` and it will leave white spaces.

Comment: @Desdenova: `"\\d+"` is for *one or more* digits, so that would also match `"count '10'"` or `"count '9999'"`. - I don't know which white space you mean. I have just generalized the pattern `"count '0','"` from the question. It can be improved if OP shows a complete example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: by typo I meant the extra `'` in the end. You were right about the `\d+`, tried both with the plus and without, seems like both are working. The spaces after and before the coma marks, log a length and you'll see.

Comment: @Desdenova: The trailing `'` is already present in the original patterns shown in the question. I cannot *guess* if that was intended or not.