# Remove part of a string before the first forward slash

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a string

```
NSString *str = @"xyz/en/ABOUT/hello";
```

I need to remove all characters before the first slash.

My output should be like this :

"/en/ABOUT/hello"

but I cannot simply replace `@"xyz"`, because the contents before the first slash are dynamic.

Comment: `rangeOfString:` should help you find the first `/`, then use if the `rangeFound.location != NSNotFound`, you can use `substringFromIndex:`.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try

Comment: I found another way NSArray *strArray = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:strArray[0] withString:@""];

Comment: If `str = @"en/en/ABOUT/hello"`, it shouldn't work. `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` would replace each one giving as result `@"//ABOUT/hello`

Comment: @Larme yes, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *str = @"xyz/en/ABOUT/hello";
NSUInteger index = [str rangeOfString:@"/"].location;
NSString *myString = [str substringFromIndex:index];
NSLog(@"final string: %@", myString);    // final string:  /en/ABOUT/hello
```

**Swift3**

```
let str = "xyz/en/ABOUT/hello"
let index = str.range(of: "/")?.lowerBound
let myString: String? = str.substring(from: index!)
print("final string: ", myString!)   // final string:  /en/ABOUT/hello
```

Answer (score 0):

first split the string:

```
NSArray *array1 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]
```

then join the string:

```
NSString *joinedString = [[array1 subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [array1 count] - 1)] componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
```

to add the first `'/'` back

```
joinedString = [@"/" stringByAppendingString:joinedString]
```

There should be a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/use-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring) way of doing this, but rarely using that unless have to.

Comment: Range is invalid, so `subarrayWithRange:` should crash.

Comment: @armnotstrong - what about `/en/`, but your joinedString returns `en/`

Comment: I did it another way and its working 
NSArray *strArray = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        
        urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:strArray[0] withString:@""];

Comment: @user6788419 what if the first pattern occur multi times?

Comment: @armnotstrong yeah  i got it

Comment: @armnotstrong it should be  [array1 count]-1 

Then its working fine

Comment: @user6788419 Yeah, have just checked that, when dealing with the range staff of arrays, I sometimes became very confused :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're working with a file path. So, use path manipulation methods:

```
@implementation NSString (MorePaths)

- (NSString *)WSSDroppingFirstRelativePathComponent
{
    NSArray * trailingComponents = [[self pathComponents] WSSDroppingFirst];
    return [NSString pathWithComponents:trailingComponents];
}

@end

@implementation NSArray (Dropping)

- (NSArray *)WSSDroppingFirst
{
    NSRange trailingRange = NSMakeRange(1, [self count] - 1);
    return [self subarrayWithRange:trailingRange];
}

@end
```

If this is actually a URL, make the category on `NSURL` instead of `NSString`.